# setInterval does not trigger the first time

Tags: javascript, scroll, setinterval

There are two timers, 
tim_change once every 5 seconds to change the slide, ie create a..
tim_scroll that scrolls the slide 35 times x 20 milliseconds apart.

Now the problem is that the first time changeSlide() is called, the slide does not scroll. 
As if tim_scroll does not work the first time. But works after that. So that in the end, the slide changes 10 seconds after the page loads, and every 5 seconds afterwards. 
The alert shows every 5 seconds always (so changeSlide() is called properly I guess).

Whats going on ? I have had another case of those timers not working properly the first time. FireFox 27.01.

```
var tim_change;
var tim_scroll;
var counter;

function init() {
    registerSlideChange();
}

function registerSlideChange() {
    tim_change = window.setInterval("changeSlide()", 5000);
}

function changeSlide() {
    alert("changeSlide");
    tim_scroll = window.setInterval("scrollFrame('scrollerID', 6, 0)", 20);
}

function scrollFrame(name, x, y) {
    var frame = document.getElementById(name);
    if(counter < 35) {
        frame.contentWindow.scrollBy(x, y);
        counter++;
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(tim_scroll);
        counter = 0;
    }
}

window.onload =init;
```

Comment: OP comment: order of functions seems to correct problems in FireFox and Internet Explorer. But Chrome still does not work, "frame.contentWindow.scrollBy(x,y)" seems to not work properly. I dont know if its because of me or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood how `setInterval` works. It does not execute the code immediately, but rather, only after the interval. For example, if you want `scrollFrame()` to execute as soon as `changeSlide()` runs, you need to call `scrollFrame()` in `changeSlide()`:

```
function changeSlide() {
    alert("changeSlide");
    scrollFrame('scrollerID', 6, 0);
    tim_scroll = window.setInterval("scrollFrame('scrollerID', 6, 0)", 20);
}
```

Similarly, if you want `changeSlide()` to execute immediately when `registerChangeSlide()` runs, you'll have to call it.

```
function registerSlideChange() {
    changeSlide();
    tim_change = window.setInterval("changeSlide()", 5000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I know that, its not the problem. The problem is that 5 seconds after the page loads, changeSlide() is called (thats good so far like you pointed out), but then scrollFrame does not start to get called 20 milliseconds after that.

Comment: Oh, I get it. I see your problem as well. Will update my answer momentarily.

Comment: Maybe not, is your problem limited to specific browsers?

Comment: The problem above  happens in FireFox 27.0.1 and InternetExplorer 11. In Google Chrome it doesnt work at all, it does not scroll at all.

Comment: Update = I changed the order of the functions and it works Ok in FireFox and IE (changed them by 'order of appearence', so init() goes to the bottom, etc).  Still does not work in Chrome. A strange thing in Chrome is that counter is always zero, although it does enter the "if(counter<35)" statement. So maybethe scrollBy() function in Chrome crashes somehow and breaks execution ?